# How to increase icon size of actionButton in SherlockActionBar?

Tags: android, icons, actionbarsherlock

To define the actionButton and set its icon, I would:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/m_login"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/login"/>
</menu>
```

---

The resulted icon(drawable/ldpi) looks very small by default: (Any way to increase the size?)

[image]

Here's the icon:

[image]

Comment: try to user bigger image icon with no paddings or if the size is not suitable for you, you can add that icon as custom view and add onclick listener to the item.

Comment: @Android-Developer Is the icon attached big enough? How would I work it out as custom view to override the sherlockactionbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to try with different sizes of the icon which you want, without no paddings until you achieve your goal. If that not suits you, you can add a custom view in actionbar and set `OnClickListener` on a button and achieve your goal. Here is a way how to do this :

```
View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_button, null); // layout which contains your button.
Button mButton = (Button) customNav.findViewById(R.id.date_num);
mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customNav);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

That should do the trick. You can use Button or ImageButton to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, btw is there other way like overriding the style of theme to achieve this?

Comment: isn't 150 * 99 high enough?

Comment: You can override theme, but you can't change menu item's size. According to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html , size and densities for different devices are already predefined for consistency.

Comment: you mean we cant set the icon layout size to be bigger?

Comment: Nope,the only way you can make icon size bigger is creating an icon without any paddings. That's the only way as far as I know  or use custom view instead.

Comment: I see now, very helpful info:) I have tried your method, but the menu button is not stick with the right hand side. Any way to replace the default menu item ?

Comment: to place your button the place you want, just use in your layout `layout_gravity` or `alignParentRight / Left` depending on your layout (Linear or Relative) and depending on the place you want to add it.

Comment: you mean the layout can be defined exactly at the my_button.xml itself? Sorry to be annoyance I'm just a starter :)

Comment: Yes! You can set your button position using your custom  xml.

Comment: I have tried, still unable to replace the old menu item place like the attachment :( Can you show me the way in example?:)

Comment: can you post the code which you are using and the result, so I can see what exactly is happening?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29089/discussion-between-roylee-and-android-developer)

Answer (score 2):

Use high resolution transparent PNG images with no padding. Follow the [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html). You can also use the [Action Bar and Tab Icon Generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=example&theme=light) to generate icons specific to the guidelines.

Comment: Besides that is there any way to hack into the sherlockactionbar to resize the icon as we like?

Comment: The sizes for menu items are fixed and hence there are design guidelines to be followed so that the appearance of the icons stays neat and slick across devices of different screen sizes and densities. So increasing the image size wont help much. So better to follow  the guidelines.

Comment: The icon generator utility that I have mentioned above is a great tool. Generates all sets of icons for you, sticks to the guidelines and saves you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: yes I have seen it, very useful indeed, thanks! By the way its not working when I uploaded my own image, it seems to generate 9 patch for me?

Comment: Something seems to be going wrong on that website at the moment. It doesnot generate 9 patch but it creates different drawables for hdpi, mdpi etc..

Comment: Okay noted :) thanks anyway! very helpful tool for a starter like me.