# SherlockActionBar: How to adjust CustomView against actionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-custom-view

**Question:**

How can I have the title back?

---

**Here's the screenshot (Missing title):**

### [image]

**Actionbar setting:**

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setTitle("My Title");
 actionBar.setIcon(drawable.dropdown_user);

 View mLogoView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.mLogoView, null);
 actionBar.setCustomView(mLogoView);

 actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

---

**mLogoView.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_merchant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/infoflex">
</ImageView>
</RelativeLayout >
```

---

Comment: can you post mLogoView?

Comment: @blackbelt You asked for it :)

Comment: the parente of the ImageView is match_parent in width and height. Can you try with wrap_content (set width and hegth to wrap_content for RelativeLayout)

Comment: @blackbelt I'd tried wrap_content, it's the same result.

Comment: @blackbelt I think you are almost there, I'd tried to set it as LinearLayout, and the title has shown, but it wouldn't align to right

Comment: did you set the layout_gravity for the ImageView? android:layout_gravity="right"

Comment: @blackbelt Yes I have done that as well, no luck, I've just updated the mLogoView with white border. You could see it spanned wide area. (RelativeLayout)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29821/discussion-between-roylee-and-blackbelt)

Comment: @blackbelt We have the solution, check the answer now my friend :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The first thing which I can think a way to fix that is try to set

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right" >
```

to your `RelativeLayout`. Because as default in Android every View is added from left to right (if you doesn't specify something else in your code).

And if that doesn't work, I would add `android:layout_width="90dip"`  or some other value depending on the image and your tests. The second option is more like a workaround, but I think it will work on all devices.

**Edit:**

As I found there is a little problem using `RelativeLayout` and Custom Views in ActionBar, so the better option is to use `LinearLayout` and set `LayoutParams` via code. Change your xml to look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/asus"    />
</LinearLayout >
```

and in your MainActivity.class use this :

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
....
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setTitle("OMG");

LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.img, null); // layout which contains your button.
actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for showing up! :) The first option is not working. The width seems to takeover the title space. Which does not happen to navigationbar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274077/how-to-increase-icon-size-of-actionbutton-in-sherlockactionbar

Comment: can you see what is happening when setting width to your relativelayout

Comment: Nothing happens. But if I would to set it as linearlayout, the title shown, but I just couldn't align the layout to right.

Comment: You can't align the imageview or layout?

Comment: I could send you the test program.

Comment: Ok, do it and I will check.

Comment: Now it works like charm! Gosh You are wizard! Thanks for the help, again. :) I learn something new today!

Comment: I have tested to write in xml, but it doesn't work :) Any reason why this only work in programmically way.

Comment: Because in your xml you can't set layout params to your root layout - `LinearLayout`, but in code you can do that while adding custom view to ActionBar. That's the whole idea.